# Pygame reset an Image after scaling it

Tags: python, image, pygame, mouse

I tried to enlarge an image by moving the mouse over the image and make it to the original size when moving away from it.
For example:

```
if ImageRect.collidepoint(mouseX,mouseY):
     Image = pygame.transform.scale(Image, (100,100))
else:
     Image = pygame.transform.scale(Image, (64,64)) #actual size of Image
```

But after moving the mouse 10 times over it , the image is getting weird.
How can I fix this?

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpCHZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some of the transforms are considered destructive. These means every
>   time they are performed they lose pixel data. Common examples of this
>   are resizing and rotating. For this reason, it is better to
>   retransform the original surface than to keep transforming an image
>   multiple times. (For example, suppose you are animating a bouncing
>   spring which expands and contracts. If you applied the size changes
>   incrementally to the previous images, you would lose detail. Instead,
>   always begin with the original image and scale to the desired size.)

Taken directly from [pygame.transform documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html)

**Work Around**

Don't change the original image each time. Instead, every time they collide just show a new image on top of the old image (since it is a larger image the old one won't be shown). Alternatively you can just hide the old image.

Example:

```
if ImageRect.collidepoint(mouseX,mouseY):
     Image2 = pygame.transform.scale(Image, (100,100))
```